# How to align site content in the center on the page

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a wordpress site where the content isn't aligned in the center on mobile. Its like the content is 5px to the right. I've tried to find it in the css code, to no avail.

Website is fralinpickups.com

Here's a screenshot : 
[image: Screenshot Here]

I've used `div {margin:auto!important}` and it fixes the problem, but creates new alignment issues on our home page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I inspected the code, I've seen where the error seems to be. In the class `.entry-content` you have both a `margin-left:5` and `margin-right:5` Both of the margins are unnecessary and are what appear to be causing the issue, just remove them from your css and everything should work.